# spring batch reads multiple files of same type object

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm trying to read data from differents csv files (same structure and column). Currently I'm using FlatFileItemReader which can only handle single file reading(not sure, point me if I'm wrong).
Here is my reader:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<HotelCSVDto> NYhotelReader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<HotelCSVDto> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(BASE_PATH + "Hotels-NY.csv"));
    reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    setHotelReader(reader);
    return reader;
}
```

I know there is a `MultiResourceItemReader`,but it does not have the methods that I'm using right now (skip line, separetor, etc). I'd like to know if there a way to read multiple files using `FlatFileItemReader`, or how to achieve same functionality of my code above using `MultiResourceItemReader`. Thanks.

Comment: `MultiResourceItemReader` takes a delegate `ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream` which can be your appropriately configured `FlatFileItemReader`.  It will iterate over the resources and use the delegate to read from them.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<HotelCSVDto> testReader() {
    MultiResourceItemReader<HotelCSVDto> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    Resource[] fileSources = new ClassPathResource[2];
    fileSources[0] = new ClassPathResource(BASE_PATH + "Hotels.csv");
    fileSources[1] = new ClassPathResource(BASE_PATH + "Hotels-NY.csv");
    reader.setResources(fileSources);
    FlatFileItemReader<HotelCSVDto> flatReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    flatReader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new DefaultRecordSeparatorPolicy());
    flatReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    setHotelReader(flatReader);
    reader.setDelegate(flatReader);
    return reader;
}
```

Thanks to @Joe Chiavaroli, I'm able to use `MultiResourceItemReader` to read different files.